# Update table record from sqlcommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-update

I have this situation: in DataEntryForm I have a dropdownlist, where user selects a letter number, and according to that inserts other related data.

I plan to change letter's status in other table by choosing in dropdownlist automatically.

I am using this code:

```
SqlParameter answertoparam = new SqlParameter("answerto", ansTo);

string commandText = "update IncomeLetters set IncomeLetters.docState_ID ='2' where income_number=('" + ansTo + "' )";

SqlCommand findincomelett = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
comm.Parameters.Add(answertoparam);
conn.Open();

findincomelett.ExecuteNonQuery();
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Unfortunately, the result is nothing.

Server is not giving error, and it simply refreshes the page that is it.

Answer (score 1):

In your posted code, you are passing the `SqlParameter` as well as passing the value as raw data. Do either of one and preferably pass it as SqlParameter like

```
        SqlParameter answertoparam = new SqlParameter("answertoparam", ansTo);
        string commandText = "update IncomeLetters set IncomeLetters.docState_ID = '2' where income_number = @answertoparam";
        SqlCommand findincomelett = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
        findincomelett.Parameters.Add(answertoparam);
        conn.Open();
        findincomelett.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Moreover, you have two `SqlCommand` object in place and calling two `ExecuteNonQuery()` on them. correct that ... see below

```
        SqlCommand findincomelett = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn); --1
        comm.Parameters.Add(answertoparam); --2

        conn.Open();

        findincomelett.ExecuteNonQuery(); --1
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); --2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to bring you here full code of the page.

Idea is: I have page for enrollment. I am passing data to DB through stored procedure (`DataInserter`).

Problem is here: during enrollment, user selects from dropdownlist number of the letter he would like to answer to, and in the end, the status of the letter on other table of DB (`IncomeLetters.tbl`), would change from "pending"('1') to "issued" ('2').

I guess, I could clear my point to you and thank you for your support!

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MaktubhoConnectionString2"].ConnectionString);
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("DataInserter", conn))
    {
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.Connection = conn;
        SqlParameter employeeparam = new SqlParameter("EmployeeSentIndex", int.Parse(ddlemployee.SelectedItem.Value));
        SqlParameter doctypeparam = new SqlParameter("doctype_ID", int.Parse(ddldoctype.SelectedItem.Value));
        SqlParameter doccharparam = new SqlParameter("docchar_ID", int.Parse(ddldocchar.SelectedItem.Value));
        SqlParameter authorityparam = new SqlParameter("authority", txtauthority.Text);
        SqlParameter subjectparam = new SqlParameter("subject", txtsubject.Text);

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string todasdate = dt.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"));
        SqlParameter entrydateparam = new SqlParameter("entrydate", todasdate);

        string Pathname = "UploadImages/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        SqlParameter imagepathparam = new SqlParameter("image_path",  Pathname);
        SqlParameter loginparam = new SqlParameter("login", "jsomon");

        comm.Parameters.Add(employeeparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(doctypeparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(doccharparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(authorityparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(subjectparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(entrydateparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(imagepathparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(loginparam);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@forlabel", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        comm.Parameters["@forlabel"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
        string ansTo = ddlAnswerTo.SelectedItem.Value;
        SqlParameter answertoparam = new SqlParameter("answertoparam", ansTo);
        string commandText = "update IncomeLetters set IncomeLetters.docState_ID = '2' where income_number = @answertoparam";
        SqlCommand findincomelett = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
        findincomelett.Parameters.Add(answertoparam);
            conn.Open();
            findincomelett.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lblresult.Visible = true;
            Image1.Visible = true;
            lblresult.Text = "Document number:";
            lblnumber.Visible = true;
            lblnumber.Text = (string)comm.Parameters["@forlabel"].Value; ;
            conn.Close();
        }

    txtauthority.Text = "";
    txtsubject.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: If you need to amend your question, **EDIT** your question - don't post a *dummy* answer to your own question.....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the issue is that the correct `IncomeLetters.docState_ID` is not updated to '2'.

You may want to debug and see what value you are getting in :

```
string ansTo = ddlAnswerTo.SelectedItem.Value;
```

The record in the database that you are expecting to be updated may not have the record that satisfies the where clause 'income_number = @answertoparam'